# Roots of quadratic eqaution lies in an AP

Tags: roots, quadratics, arithmetic-progressions, discriminant

[image]
I tried finding the common difference between the roots but didnt know what to do next. 
if someone could tell me how to solve this or give a headstart itll be a lot helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

The formulae for sum and product of roots gives $\frac{b^2-4ac}{a^2}=(\alpha - \beta)^2$.
Compare this with the same result for the other quadratic and note that $\alpha-\beta=\gamma-\delta$.

NOTE

$(\alpha - \beta)^2=(\alpha + \beta)^2-4\alpha\beta =\frac{b^2}{a^2}-4\frac{ac}{a^2}$